# Multiple Class Names - getelementsbyclassname

Tags: javascript, dom

Basically I want a logo to change, there are 2 current logos, individually labelled with the classes... 'Header-branding-logo' & 'Mobile-bar-branding-logo'. I can change either one of them, but not at both at the same time.

I can't seem to figure out where I need to put it. Can anyone help?

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementsByClassName('Header-branding-logo')[0].src = 'https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a9e8da0aa49a18379207907/t/5ac52f062b6a28a603df30cf/1522872070340/GBL+Shop+-+Black+1500.png';  
   };
 </script>
```

***UPDATE***

Thanks to the genius below, this now works for me

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Header-branding-logo,.Mobile-bar-branding-logo');

elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.src = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a9e8da0aa49a18379207907/t/5ac52f062b6a28a603df30cf/1522872070340/GBL+Shop+-+Black+1500.png"
})
    };
 </script>
```

Comment: You need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `querySelectorAll` function

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Header-branding-logo,.Mobile-bar-branding-logo');

elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.src = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a9e8da0aa49a18379207907/t/5ac52f062b6a28a603df30cf/1522872070340/GBL+Shop+-+Black+1500.png"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
window.onload = function() {
    var classes = document.querySelectorAll(".Header-branding-logo, .Mobile-bar-branding-logo") // Gets multiple classes whereas getElementsByClassName() fetches only one. Also dont miss the '.' before classnames here
    for(i = 0; i <= classes.length; i++){
        classes[i].src = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a9e8da0aa49a18379207907/t/5ac52f062b6a28a603df30cf/1522872070340/GBL+Shop+-+Black+1500.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it didn't seem to work. Thanks for offering your solution. Maybe it can help someone else.

Comment: Hi, there was an error which I've edited and  it works fine now. You can give a try if you're interested.